# How Do I access an iPhone mounted at gphoto2://[usb:001,003]/?

Tags: iphone, bash, mount

I need to cp (or dd) some files.
I tried this: https://superuser.com/questions/281986/bashterminal-access-to-camera-files-mounted-as-gphoto2-usb001-003-dcim?answertab=active#tab-top ; But, the folder (.gvfs) is empty.

```
Volume(0): iPhone
  Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorGPhoto2)
  ids:
   unix-device: '/dev/bus/usb/001/003'
  activation_root=gphoto2://[usb:001,003]/
  themed icons:  [camera-photo]
  can_mount=1
  can_eject=0
  should_automount=1
  Mount(0): iPhone -> gphoto2://[usb:001,003]/
    Type: GProxyShadowMount (GProxyVolumeMonitorGPhoto2)
    default_location=gphoto2://[usb:001,003]/
    themed icons:  [camera-photo]
    x_content_types: x-content/image-dcf
    can_unmount=1
    can_eject=0
    is_shadowed=0
Mount(1): iPhone -> gphoto2://[usb:001,003]/
  Type: GDaemonMount
  default_location=gphoto2://[usb:001,003]/
  themed icons:  [camera-photo]  [camera]
  x_content_types: x-content/image-dcf
  can_unmount=1
  can_eject=0
  is_shadowed=1
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Ubuntu 12.10, GVFS mounts are now under `/run/user/<your_username>/gvfs/` instead of `~/.gvfs/`. So you should find your files under this new directory.

Answer (score 1):

In Xubuntu 13.10, I found my Canon Powershot at

/run/user/1000/gvfs/ . . .

It was difficult to find that information; hope it helps.

Comment: There is already a more general answer which encompasses yours. Instead of adding a new answer, you can up-vote the existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use 'dd' you don't need a mount. Just use the block device.

`/dev/bus/usb/001/003`

if you

`dd if=/dev/bus/usb/001/003 of=~/images.img` you're going to end up with a flat filesystem that you will still need to mount to make use of the pictures however.